# is it better to have IBM MQ connection using EJB in spring batch processor or at writer?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, ibm-mq, ejb-3.0

Need to read a flat-file using spring batch and push success records into IBM MQ using EJB (MDB) hosted in WebSphere server and error records should be written to a flat-file.
Is it better practice to have EJB in the processor or in writer ?

Answer (score 0):

> push success records into IBM MQ using EJB (MDB) hosted in WebSphere server

This is a write operation so it is better implemented with an `ItemWriter`.

> error records should be written to a flat-file

Those records can be written to the file using a [`SkipListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/SkipListener.html) depeneding on when the error occurs (during the process or the write, see methods `onSkipInProcess` and `onSkipInWrite`).